# Operating on low part of ARM NEON vector efficiently with intrinsics

Tags: arm, intrinsics, neon

ARM provides intrinsics to operate on high portion of intrinsic vector types but I can't see equivalent to operate on the low part.

Consider simple example to calculate residue of the two buffers with 16 elements of 8 bit (8 bit - 8 bit = result in 16 bit).

```
uint8x16_t src0, src1;
int16x8_t dst0, dst1;
src0 = vld1q_u8((uint8_t const *)src0_);
src1 = vld1q_u8((uint8_t const *)src1_);

dst0 = vreinterpretq_s16_u16(vsubl_u8(vget_low_u8(src0), vget_low_u8(src1)));
dst1 = vreinterpretq_s16_u16(vsubl_high_u8(src0, src1));
```

To operate on high part of registers we have `vsubl_high_u8`.  But to operate on low, first need to perform extract low of the input register (which are with some latency) and then use sub instruction.

Asm provides access to low and high separately via separate register names (for 32-bit ARM NEON), so this is only a question of intrinsics.

(Editor's note: AArch64 does have separate low/high asm instructions because every  `s` (32-bit) and `d` (64-bit) register is the low part of a separate `q` (128-bit) vector register.)

Comment: *first need to perform extract low of the input register (which are with some latency)* - are you sure?  I think the idea is that `vget_low_u8` can be free, i.e. zero asm instructions, just keep the C type system happy.  In practice that's sometimes not the case, and it does compile to a wasted instruction.  For some reason (probably the complicated partial-register model) compilers do much worse with ARM NEON than with equivalent x86 SSE or PPC Altivec intrinsics; last I checked was maybe a year ago so possibly recent clang and/or gcc has gotten better.

Comment: @PeterCordes "https://static.docs.arm.com/ihi0073/e/IHI0073E_arm_neon_intrinsics_ref.pdf?_ga=2.184681195.376134140.1579584907-1269412853.1576570485" The link provides mapping of asm to intrinsic. the get_low/get_hign maps to DUP, for A76 - DUP has latency of 3/2.

Comment: Well that's just silly documentation.  https://godbolt.org/z/ad2fVM shows that GCC and clang compile them to zero instructions for a function that just does `return vget_low_u8(v);`.  This is what's supposed to happen as part of a larger function, unless compilers shoot themselves in the foot by *actually* using an instruction to copy instead of just reading the `d` register.

Comment: Thank you @PeterCordes, The link is very helpful. My workstation compiler is gcc version 5.4.0 (aarch64), If I supply that in the link provided, it does generate extra instruction. So the choice of compiler will matter for performance. https://godbolt.org/z/4Mk4wt

Comment: Oh, you're compiling for AArch64?  I guessed wrong in my edit, I thought the asm feature you were talking about was ARM32 having each Q register composed of a pair of D registers.

Comment: yes, I was talking about aarch64. I think, your previous both the comments are still valid (regardless of architecture), Am i correct?

Comment: Yes, it applies for low-half stuff.  IIRC efficient compilation for ARM32 was even harder, relying on the compiler to optimize away extract_high intrinsics as well as low if you wanted to e.g. add the high and low halves of a 128-bit vector to each other.  (Which in practice they didn't reliably do, although these days maybe that's better. The fact that GCC5.4 had a missed optimization here is a good sign that the widespread missed optimizations that are a huge problem for ARM intrinsics may be less bad in recent compilers). I guess we can leave the question alone since the answer is the same.